# Change value in main using void sub-function

Tags: c, pointers, void

I am having trouble with this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void change_number(int *x);

int main()
{
   int x;
   printf("Enter the number x: ")
   scanf("%d", &x);
   printf("In the main program: x = %d\n", x);
   change_number(&x);
   printf("In the main program: x = %d\n", x);
   return 0;
}
void change_number(int *x)
{
   x = *x+3;
   printf("In the subroutine: x = %d\n", x);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Enter the number x: 555
In the main program: x = 555
In the subroutine: x = 558
In the main program: x = 558
```

Two notes:

1. I cannot modify main, or anything that comes before it. I can *only* modify the `void change_number` function, and the code inside it is my own code.
2. I cannot get the required output – my code only outputs `x+3` in the subroutine, but doesn't change it in the main program.

How would I go about changing the value in the main routine? Please keep in mind that I am very new to C, and don't know many things yet (in fact, I just covered pointers yesterday).

Comment: You need to compile the code with a standard C compiler. If you for example have the GCC compiler, you can turn it into a standard C compiler with the options `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code

```
void change_number(int *x)
{
   x = *x+3;
   printf("In the subroutine: x = %d\n", x);
}
```

should read

```
void change_number(int *x)
{
   *x = *x+3;
   printf("In the subroutine: *x = %d\n", *x);
}
```

This will use the pointers as intended (you need to dereference them on the LHS as well)

Answer (score 5):

I think an answer to the OP question needs a little bit explanation as C syntax may be confusing at times:

The function is declared as

```
void change_number(int *x)
```

The `*` means that the input parameter `x` is a pointer to a variable of type int. In other words `x` represents a location in memory.

---

Inside the function:

`x` is the address in memory of the `int` value

`*x` is the "content" of the memory address pointed by `x`

So, as other correctly pointed out, the function should be written as

```
void change_number(int *x)
{
   *x = *x+3;
   printf("In the subroutine: x = %d\n", *x);
}
```

Because as you act on `*x` you're acting on the content pointed by `x`

---

What is happening into `main()` ?

`x` is an `int` variable.

And you call:

```
change_number(&x);
```

The amplersand `&` means that you're not passing the value of `x`.

Instead you're passing a pointer to `x`, in other words the address in memory where the content of `x` is stored.

In other-other words `x` is passed by reference.

---

A final note: when writing a program in **c** (well, in any language, but expecially in c) the compiler **warnings**/errors and the debugger are your best friends.

Furthermore a good **IDE** will show you warnings as you type the code.

Anyway... the compiler should have warned you that

```
x = *x+3;
```

involves an implicit conversion from a `int` to `int *` (pointer to int) and most likely is a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
*x = *x+3;
```

instead of

```
x = *x + 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

What a function does with its parameters is, it makes a copy to work on and once the function's scope is ended, the copy is released which cannot change a value of a parameter passed to a function from outside.This is where pointers come in.
when passing a pointer to a function, think of it as a copy of the real address where in your case `x` is stored.

Thus in order to use x or change x, you have to use or change respectively  `*x`(and it gets later dereferenced in the main program by `&`.

so like many others mentioned `x = *x+3;` should be `*x = *x+3;` and you'll get the desired results

Comment: ...and `printf("In the subroutine: x = %d\n", *x);` as the OP wants to print the value of x and not its address

Comment: @Paolo: Yes, off course. I've seen all the other answers, and kind of forgot that OP put x instead of *x in the printf in his code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing in the change function you can also print in the main function by doing
*x=*x+3